# How to configure Web API2 routes with 2 properties using slash instead of questionmark

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I've made a very simple `WebApi2` project just for testing purposes. I have a class `Dog` in `Models` :

```
public class Dog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Breed { get; set; }
}
```

And I have `DogController`. What I am trying to do is to make the HTTP request working with this URL - `localhost:555/api/dog/2/breed/pitbull` but all I am able to do till now is making it possible to use 2 properties but like this:
`localhost:555/api/dog/2?breed=pitbull`. When I try the first option I get `Error 404 - Not Found`.

This is my `WebApiConfig`:

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
             name: "dogroutewithbreed",
             routeTemplate: "api/dogcontroller/{id}/{breed}"
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DogRouteWithId",
            routeTemplate: "api/DogController/{id}"
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DEFAULT",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

And in my `DogController` I have these two methods:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public Dog GetDogById(int id)
    {
        List<Dog> dogs = new List<Dog>();
        dogs.Add(new Dog { Id = 1, Name = "Sharo", Breed = "Ovcharka" });
        dogs.Add(new Dog { Id = 2, Name = "bimba", Breed = "pitbull" });
        dogs.Add(new Dog { Id = 3, Name = "Reksi", Breed = "Koker" });

        return dogs.Where(d => d.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public Dog Breed(int id, string breed)
    {
        List<Dog> dogs = new List<Dog>();
        dogs.Add(new Dog { Id = 1, Name = "Sharo", Breed = "Ovcharka" });
        dogs.Add(new Dog { Id = 2, Name = "bimba", Breed = "pitbull" });
        dogs.Add(new Dog { Id = 3, Name = "Reksi", Breed = "Koker" });

        return dogs.Where(d => d.Id == id && d.Breed == "pitbull")
                   .FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Comment: try with this url: localhost:555/api/dog/2/pitbul

Answer (score 0):

use attribute routing instead.. for more info: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2